# browser router not being exported from react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am tring to use the react router dom to make different pages so that it can go to different pages on click but the app does not compile since browser router is not being imported. I just copy pasted it straight from the website. Can someone tell me where the mistake is and how to fix it

App,js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './components/Home';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
import Detail from './components/Detail';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='detail'>
            <Detail />
          </Route>
          <Route path='/'>
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
      <Home />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

package.json
{

```
"name": "disneyplus-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.6.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: Error page]

Comment: Try to use `from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 0):

You are using version 6 of `react-router-dom` and you ***don't*** have `react-router` specified in your package.json file.

Import the components from `react-router-dom` and convert to using the RRDv6 components. The `Switch` component was replaced by a `Routes` component that ***must*** wrap the `Route` components. The `Route` components also now render their routed components on the `element` prop ***as JSX***.

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './components/Home';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Detail from './components/Detail';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='detail' element={<Detail />} />
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
      <Home />
    </div>
  )
}
```